# Increase Plot layout and reduce the legend list

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Below is my code to plot Stacked BarPlot

```
ggplot(data = mdata, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.7)), 
        legend.key.size = unit(0.5, "cm")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x)x*100) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  ylab("Species Percentage") + 
  xlab("Samples")
```

OutputPlot:
[image]

As you can see from the plot my Species legends are split in to 5 column list, which takes the 50% of the total plot layout.

Is there a way to make/convert legend list in to only 2 or 3 column so that area above and below will be covered and BarPlot can be widened.

Also to make Legend Text Bold its looking blurred with many legends

Answer (score 2):

You can set any number of columns with the `ncol` argument in `guide_legend()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- cbind(car = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)

ggplot(dat, aes(mpg, wt, colour = car)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3))
```

[image]

EDIT: As Z.Lin pointed out, for fill scales; replace `scale_colour_*` by `scale_fill_*`.

Comment: Hi, I Added still its same, no changes

Comment: @Kiran You may want  `scale_fill_discrete(guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3))` (instead of `scale_colour_***` in your case.

Comment: any idea how to make the legend text readable like Bold, now it looks Blurred in the image

Comment: Can i have your linkedIn contact, I see You are Computational Biologist, same domain as mine Bioinformatics

Comment: for bold text you can add `+ theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "bold"))`. And good point @Z.Lin, I'll edit it in the answer.